# SSRS 2008: Unable to restore encryption key

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs

I have migrated SQL server 2005 database to sql server 2008 using side by side upgrade. I have copied Reportserver and reportservertempdb database across and configured SQl server Reporting services 2008 to use this new database. I am not able to restore SSRS key over to new SSRS 2008 server. The key restore reports:

```
Microsoft.ReportingServices.WmiProvider.WMIProviderException: An error occurred when attempting to connect to the report server remote procedure call (RPC) end point. Verify that the Report Server Windows service is running, and then retry the operation.

 ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800706B3): The RPC server is not listening. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706B3)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WmiProvider.RSWmiAdmin.ThrowOnError(ManagementBaseObject mo)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WmiProvider.RSWmiAdmin.RestoreEncryptionKey(Byte[] encryptedBytes, String password)
   at ReportServicesConfigUI.WMIProvider.RSReportServerAdmin.RestoreEncryptionKey(Byte[] encryptedBytes, String password)
```

I can open `SSRS` website but just not the encrypted content because of failure in restoring `SSRS` key.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 4):

Late reply, but I just ran into this issue with moving SSRS 2008 R2 to a new server.

Had the same problem as described above, but going through the Database and Credentials wizards fixed it for me, even though I made no changes and everything was displayed correctly.

Go to Database -> Change Credentials/Change Database in the configuration manager and click through both wizards.

After that I was able to restore the keys.

Comment: This worked for me too, very bizarre.

Answer (score 1):

What error do you get in Reporting Services Configuration Manager when you try and restore the encryption key through there?

Comment: I only know one way to restore the encryption key that is using Reporting Services configuration manager which I have posted above.                                                                 Microsoft.ReportingServices.WmiProvider.WMIProviderException: An error occurred when attempting to connect to the report server remote procedure call (RPC) end point. Verify that the Report Server Windows service is running, and then retry the operation.

Comment: You can also restore keys from the command line with the RSKEYMGMT utility.  The syntax is: rskeymgmt -a -f a:\backupkey\keys -p <password>.  I would give this a try and see if you get the same error.  Link to MS regarding this utility:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162822.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think we need to go through verifying the credentials and database settings before applying the key. I had a similar issue and went through all of them and it did seem to refresh. After that I was able to restore the key without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

My Solution:

On the server I went into "Reporting Services Configuration Manager"
-> Service Account -> Changed to network service Account -> Apply-> Used my current user credentials to login to SQL on the prompt -> changed back to Virtual Service -> Apply -> current credentials again

It applied permissions and then allowed me to import the key